# AWS ElasticSearch - Number of nodes doubled after adding two data nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

We recently increased the number of the data nodes of our ElasticSearch domain (version 7.10) from 2 to 4. We also have three dedicated master nodes running. However, the number of nodes shown in the details of the domain, as well as in the CloudWatch metrics, is now 12 (instead of 7 as we'd expect, 3 master + 4 data).

We read in the documentation of OpenSearch that this could be due to the so-called "Blue/Green Deployment", where a new environment is created during domain updates. We think this might be the case as the total number of nodes (12), is the sum of the 5 nodes we previously had plus the 7 nodes we want to have in the new domain.

Unfortunately, the nodes count has been stable at 12 for weeks now. The domain status is Green and Kibana works just fine. How can we know if there's something wrong with the new configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: this is not an Elasticsearch issue. please contact aws as it is due to the deployment process they use

Comment: Hello Mark, thanks for your comment. What do you mean by "due to the deployment process they use"?

Comment: I mean whatever they are using to deploy and manage the Elasticsearch cluster

Comment: @madipi Did the nodes came back at count of 7 as expected ? AWS Elasticsearch performs a blue/green deployment. This behavior might be possible because of this. For reference, you can read here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-configuration-changes.html

Comment: @Harshit no unfortunately it's still at 12

Comment: Can you check if the domain is still in Processing state? That would likely be the reason for 12 node count.

Comment: No, the UI showed it as "Active". We ended up recreating it from scratch.